# kendo ui mobile listview for displaying checkbox(switch) dynamically

Tags: listview, dynamic, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

**Requirement:**
i need a checkbox with in the listview li tag which will create dynamically

**Script**

```js
$('#HandlingUnitsResults').append('<li  id=' + 3 + '><a class="km-listview-link" data-role="listview-link"><table><tr><td><div><input type="checkbox" id="chkSwitch1" data-role="switch" checked="checked" data-on-label="Pass"
```

```html
<div class="pageContent" data-role="view">
<div>
    <ul id="HandlingUnitsResults" data-bind="source:onGetPartHandlingUnits" data-role="listview"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-template instead of append

```
<ul id="HandlingUnitsResults" data-bind="source:onGetPartHandlingUnits" data-role="listview" data-template="your-template"></ul>

<script id="your-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <!--your code -->
</script>
```

You can put anything inside the template, button, checkbox, etc.

Here's the example link - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/source